# Hibernate Validation does not look up error messages in a Spring boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

This is my Spring boot project set up.[image: Project Set up]

I have a standard Spring boot JPA stack in which I am trying to validate the state of the instance variables. My bean is as follows:

Configuration

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationHelper {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(this.messageSource());
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

Model class

```
@Table(name = "user_station", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "station_id", name = "station_index_station_id"),
    @Index(columnList = "station_name", name="station_index_name"),
    @Index(columnList = "hd_enabled", name = "station_index_hd_enabled")
})
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"createdTimeStamp", "updatedTimestamp"}, callSuper = true)
@ToString(exclude = {"createdTimeStamp", "updatedTimestamp"}, callSuper = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Station extends IError {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    // Represents a station id for the user.
    @Column(name="station_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "{station.id.empty}")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^K|W[A-Za-z0-9\\-].*$", message = "{station.id.name.not.valid}")
    private String stationId;

    @Column(name="station_name", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "{station.name.empty}")
    private String stationName;

    @Column(name = "hd_enabled")
    private Boolean hdEnabled;

    @Column(name="call_sign", nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty(message = "{station.call.sign.empty}")
    private String callSign;

    @Column(name="user_created_timestamp")
    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalDateTime createdTimeStamp;

    @Column(name="user_modified_timestamp")
    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalDateTime updatedTimestamp;

    /**
     * Initialises the timestamps prior to update or insertions.
     *
     * <p>The implementation ensures that time stamps would always reflect the time when entities
     * were persisted or updated.
     */
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void setTimestamps() {
        LocalDateTime utcNow = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        if (this.createdTimeStamp == null) {
            this.createdTimeStamp = utcNow;
        }
        this.updatedTimestamp = utcNow;
        if (this.hdEnabled == null) {
            this.hdEnabled = Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Getters, Setters, Equals and HashCode functions.
}
```

Unit tests

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= {App.class})
public class StationTest {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    private Station station;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.station = new Station();
    }


    @Test
    public void testValidator_allNulls() {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Station>> constraintViolations =
            this.validator.validate(this.station);
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(constraintViolations.isEmpty(), Is.is(false));
        for (ConstraintViolation<Station> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
            System.out.println(constraintViolation.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my output

```
. . . . Rest of the stack trace omitted . . . .

     2018-12-01 23:30:38.532  INFO 21297 --- [           main] com.iheartmedia.model.StationTest        : Starting StationTest on Kartiks-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 21297 (started by krishnanand in /Users/krishnanand/projects/iheartmedia)
2018-12-01 23:30:38.533 DEBUG 21297 --- [           main] com.iheartmedia.model.StationTest        : Running with Spring Boot v2.0.5.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.9.RELEASE
2018-12-01 23:30:38.539  INFO 21297 --- [           main] com.iheartmedia.model.StationTest        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-01 23:30:38.596  INFO 21297 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6892b3b6: startup date [Sat Dec 01 23:30:38 PST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-01 23:30:39.565  INFO 21297 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b7d31eab] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-12-01 23:30:39.730  INFO 21297 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-12-01 23:30:39.871  INFO 21297 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-12-01 23:30:39.903  INFO 21297 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-01 23:30:39.917  INFO 21297 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-12-01 23:30:40.030  INFO 21297 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-12-01 23:30:40.031  INFO 21297 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-12-01 23:30:40.066  INFO 21297 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-12-01 23:30:40.196  INFO 21297 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2018-12-01 23:30:40.652  INFO 21297 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-01 23:30:40.985  INFO 21297 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2018-12-01 23:30:41.351  INFO 21297 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-12-01 23:30:41.586  INFO 21297 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6892b3b6: startup date [Sat Dec 01 23:30:38 PST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-01 23:30:41.624  WARN 21297 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-12-01 23:30:41.658  INFO 21297 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/iheartmedia/stations],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.iheartmedia.model.Station> com.iheartmedia.controller.StationController.retrieveAllStations()
2018-12-01 23:30:41.660  INFO 21297 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/iheartmedia/station],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.iheartmedia.dto.StationMixin> com.iheartmedia.controller.StationController.createStation(com.iheartmedia.model.Station,org.springframework.validation.Errors)
2018-12-01 23:30:41.660  INFO 21297 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/iheartmedia/station],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.iheartmedia.dto.StationMixin> com.iheartmedia.controller.StationController.deleteStation(com.iheartmedia.model.Station)
2018-12-01 23:30:41.663  INFO 21297 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-12-01 23:30:41.664  INFO 21297 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-12-01 23:30:41.687  INFO 21297 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-12-01 23:30:41.687  INFO 21297 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-12-01 23:30:41.979  INFO 21297 --- [           main] com.iheartmedia.model.StationTest        : Started StationTest in 3.704 seconds (JVM running for 4.431)
{station.call.sign.empty}
{station.name.empty}
{station.id.empty}
2018-12-01 22:11:10.360  INFO 18663 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@6892b3b6: startup date [Sat Dec 01 22:11:06 PST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-01 22:11:10.363  INFO 18663 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-01 22:11:10.364  INFO 18663 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-12-01 22:11:10.367  INFO 18663 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

messages.properties Resource bundle

```
station.not.found=Station {0} was not found
station.id.empty=Station ID can not be empty.
station.id.format.not.valid=Station ID ${validatedValue} is not valid. Station ID should start with either W or K.
station.name.empty=Station name can not be empty.
station.call.sign.empty=Station call sign can not be empty.
```

Our dependency tree

[image: Project Dependency Tree]

I have read the following

1. [Custom error messaging on Hibernate Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442969/custom-error-messaging-on-hibernate-validation)
2. [Custom Message Key in Hibernate validator not working with message.property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673930/custom-message-key-in-hibernate-validator-not-working-with-message-property)
3. [Does Spring Boot automatically resolve message keys in javax and hibernate validation annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149358/does-spring-boot-automatically-resolve-message-keys-in-javax-and-hibernate-valid?rq=1)

but I can not still figure out what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

Upon @Jonathan Johx's suggestion, I changed the basename of the ResourceBundleMessage to `messages` (Updated the code snippet as well), but I still get the error.

Comment: I guess in your Test class `Station` object members was null. (As it is created using `this.station = new Station()` ). And you already tell in validator rules that can't be empty. e.g: `stationId`, `stationName`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is intended to be null. That is why the validation failed. But the message keys are not being looked up for some reason.

Comment: Can you try `messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the classpath: does reference to root of folder which is ConfigurationHelper class, it's not found. Try to rename file name to ***ValidationMessages***.properties which is used by Validator and update the following line:

```
messageSource.setBasenames("ValidationMessages");
```

**UPDATED**

If you want to use validation messages by default then you have to create a file called:

> ValidationMessages.properties

And add properties that you consider necessary.

Comment: It's OK, I saw your  message.properties file that has **>** symbol I'm not sure why eclipse is taking like folder I think so.

Comment: IDE is wrapping the text.

Comment: if you change to ValidationMessages.properties should work. even when you don't put the ConfigurationHelper  class

Comment: Just the basename to "ValidationProperties"?

Comment: ValidationMessages.properties file as well. rename it.

Comment: Your suggestion to change the message property name to ValidateMessage worked for me. Can you update the answer in your original message so that I can upvote your answer?

Comment: Actually, it was your suggestion to create ValidationMessages.properties that clinched it.